# Will the Egyptian consulate in Germany issue a visa to a South African with dual German citizenship using their South African passport?

Tags: visas, dual-nationality, south-african-citizens, egypt, german-citizens

I have dual German and South African citizenship. Presently I am in Germany.

I want to enter Egypt using my South African passport. However South Africans need to apply for a visa before flying to Egypt (e-visa and visa-on-arrival not possible).

I thought of sending my South African passport to the Egyptian consulate in Berlin. However the South African passport has no visa for Germany.

Will the Egyptians issue me a visa?

Comment: Germany will issue you a *second* German passport in cases like this.

Comment: Egypt and Israel have been at peace and maintained diplomatic relations since 1979. D you have any concrete reason to think an Israeli stamp would count against you for an Egyptian visa?

Comment: (On the other hand, Wikipedia reports that **Sudan** refuses admission to travelers with Israeli passport stamps, so that is probably what you _ought_ to be asking about.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, my concern is Sudan. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Egyptian consulate in Berlin issued me a 30 day multiple entry tourist visa on my South African passport.

**My application consisted of**

1. application form (for 30 day tourist visa)
2. original South African passport
3. copy of my South Africa passport
4. copy of my German passport
5. copy of german registration document (Anmelde Bestaetigung)
6. hotel reservation for 2 nights in Cairo (confirmation from booking.com)
7. return flight reservation
8. 2 bio metric ID photos
9. Eur 38 in cash

**Costs**

1. I sent everything via registered mail (cost about Eur10).
2. The visa was free (the consulate sent me the Eur38 back).

**Processing time**
 1 working day. Sent on Wednesday by registered mail. Received back on Friday.

I applied in October 2018 and about 2.5 months before departure.